# Why do I need to white-list my IP every next day

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, backend

I'm a beginner and creating a basic back-end application with `Node.js`, `Express.js` and `Mongoose` for learning purpose. My DB is placed at [Atlas-Mongo DB](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) site. I set the entire configuration with the free tier, whitelisted my IP and all went smooth. On the first day, I was even able to test my API's which saved, read contents from DB using `Postman`.

But the next day, when I started again, the server failed with `MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to testcluster-shard-00-01-*****.mongodb.net:28907 2 closed.`

After lot of trial and error, I found that for some reason my IP was blacklisted again, and hence I manually needed to visit Atlas MongoDB site and again white-list my IP.

Now, this happens every day. Every day the server is unable to connect to DB and I need to manually white list my IP again.

I'm a front-end guy so I really don't understand jargons like ports, server, crons, middleware, server-hosting, Db-hosting, IP whitelisting and Network stuff: to sum up, I really don't understand how this magical and mysterious backend works, Have I messed up something during MongoDB configuration?

Comment: It sounds like either the whitelist has an expiry, or your IP is dynamic - or both!  Are you having to add the *same* IP address?

Comment: Coincidentally every time I whitelisted my IP, I saw a new number being updated.

Comment: If your IP address changes dailyyou can use the Atlas API to whitelist your address dynamically each day. https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/api/whitelist-api/

Comment: Make sure to remove the old address.

Comment: Telcos sell fixed IP address at a higher price. So for most consumer accounts they get dynamic, temporary IP addresses that can change periodically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, the issue would be that your IP address is dynamic and happens to be changing everyday.

Because your database is just for development and testing purposes, the easiest solution would be to whitelist all IP addresses.

This can be done by whitelisting the IP `0.0.0.0/0`

Comment: How to whitelist the IP 0.0.0.0/0 and where ?

Comment: @Jyotirmoy you can whitelist IP addresses from the `Network Access` tab which is located on this endpoint -> `security/network/accessList`