# Next-Auth gives error on sign in: "API handler should not return a value, received object."

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I'm using `next-auth@4.22.1` with `next@13.4.7` and Typescript. Whenever I use the `signIn()` function, it goes through sign in as normal, but then print the following line to the server's console: API handler should not return a value, received object. I am not signed in after doing this.

I've checked my `[...nextauth].ts` file and can't find any errors. The code is below:

```
import clientPromise from "@/lib/mongodbadapter";
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@next-auth/mongodb-adapter";
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import DiscordProvider from "next-auth/providers/discord";
import GitHubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
    adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
    providers: [
        DiscordProvider({
            clientId: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID!,
            clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET!
        }),
        GitHubProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID!,
            clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET!
        })
    ]
}

export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

I've wrapped all HTML elements in a SessionProvider, like so:

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps: { session, ...pageProps } }: AppProps) {
  return <SessionProvider session={session}>
    <Navbar />
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </SessionProvider>
}
```

In my index.ts, I log session, like so:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx: any) {
  return {
    props: {
        session: await getServerSession(ctx.req, ctx.res, authOptions)
    }
  }
}
```

The server log is this:

```
undefined
- wait compiling /api/auth/[...nextauth] (client and server)...
- event compiled successfully in 265 ms (63 modules)
API handler should not return a value, received object.
API handler should not return a value, received object.
undefined
```

The undefined come from where I log the session. The compiling is from me returning to the index.ts page after signing in.

Even though session is undefined, my database (I'm using `@next-auth/mongodb-adapter@1.1.3`) has the relevant user and account documents.

What do I need to change to avoid this error and make it actually sign me in, or is it an issue with Next-Auth that's out of my control?

Edit: I confirmed my IP is allowed in my MongoDB Atlas instance.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for the warning 'API handler should not return a value, received object'?

Comment: Not yet, but I haven't worked too much on this issue.

Comment: Like your code I had ```export default NextAuth(authOptions)``` in ```[...nextauth].ts```. In a repo I saw someone using  ```const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)
export { handler as GET, handler as POST }``` instead. This solved the issue for me. I don't have an explanation for it. With Prisma the first option was fine, but with other adapters clearly not.

Comment: I tried your solution, but that gave me ```Type Error: resolver is not a function```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same issue.
Just changed *[...nextauth].ts*

**from:**

```
export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

**to:**

```
const authHandler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export default async function handler(...params: any[]) {
  await authHandler(...params);
}
```

Hope it helps.

What we're doing here is [initializing NextAuth on its "advanced" form](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/initialization#advanced-initialization) instead of using its simpler form. You can read more about it in the link but it let's you access variables inside the request and response objects. For example, you could access req.cookies.

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much for help.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue, and when I reopened the Mongo-Atlas website, it showed that my current IP address wasn't added, so after clicking on "add current IP" the issue was solved.

Comment: I checked and made sure my IP was allowed in my Atlas instace. Still didn't work though.

Comment: Check out this solution: [Why do I need to white-list my IP every next day](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61597251/11080421)